# Feature Engineering with Standardized Data

Tags: standardization, feature-engineering

I'm relatively new to feature engineering, but at a high-level what I understand that it does is takes various features in a dataset (perhaps two, perhaps more) and combines them in such a way using various mathematical functions (polynomials, rational differences, etc.) to produce a new feature.

Since I'm relatively new to this, my question is two-parts:

1.) should feature engineering be performed on features that have been Standardized or Non-Standardized values?
2.) What is the reasoning?